# (has extras) error when service runs in the app and force close

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm doing a call tracking application...

In my app, a service named callService, which takes the call from call log and saves to DB, and retrieves. The code works perfectly.

The service starts when a toggle button becomes active. it's called using 
setRepeating() function of AlarmManager. The repeat time set to 5000, and to avoid duplication in the entry call details into DB, used sharedpreference to save last entered time in milliseconds.  the call details enters to DB, by checking the last enterd calltime.

the callService.java is given below.

callService.java:

```
import java.sql.Date;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;

import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.provider.CallLog;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class callService extends Service
{

DBManager db;
Cursor managedCursor;
String CallName,CallNumber,CallType,CallDate,CallTime,CallDuration,CallDATETIME, AmOrPm;
long CallTimeMilli;
Context context=this;
long timeShared;
SharedPreferences sh;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db=new DBManager(this);
    sh=(SharedPreferences) this.getSharedPreferences("LastCallLogEntryTime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+timeShared, 3000).show();
}
@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getCallDetails();

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void getCallDetails() 
{
    //StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();


    managedCursor=context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int number=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int name=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

    //buffer.append("Call Details: ");
    //int a=managedCursor.getCount();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside GetCallDetails Function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    while(managedCursor.moveToNext())
    {

        timeShared=sh.getLong("Time", 0);
        String[] str={"0","0","0"};
        String[] a={"0","0","0"};
        String[] b={"0","0","0"};

        int dd=0, mm=0, yy=0, hh=0,mn=0,sec=0;
        CallName = managedCursor.getString(name);
        CallNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
        String cType = managedCursor.getString( type );
        //String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );

        long CallTimeMilli= managedCursor.getLong(date);
        //Toast.makeText(context, ""+seconds, 3000).show();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        CallDATETIME = formatter.format(new Date(CallTimeMilli));

        str=CallDATETIME.split(" ");
        CallDate=str[0];
        CallTime=str[1]+" "+str[2];
        //AmOrPm=str[2];


        /*//a=CallDate.split("-");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a[0]+" "+a[1]+" "+a[2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dd=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
        mm=Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
        yy=Integer.parseInt(a[2]);

        //b=CallTime.split(":");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), b[0]+" "+b[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        hh=Integer.parseInt(b[0]);
        mn=Integer.parseInt(b[1]);
        sec=Integer.parseInt(b[2]);


        //Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        //calendar.set(yy, mm, dd, hh, mn, 0);
        calendar.set(calendar.YEAR, yy);
        calendar.set(calendar.MONTH, mm);
        calendar.set(calendar.DATE, dd);
        calendar.set(calendar.HOUR, hh);
        calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, mn);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, sec);      
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //CallTimeMilli=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+CallTimeMilli, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        */
        CallDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );

        CallType = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt( cType );
        switch( dircode ) 
        {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            CallType = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            CallType = "INCOMING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            CallType = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        //buffer.append( "\nPerson Name:-- "+CallName+"\nPhone Number:--- "+CallNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+CallType+" \nCall Date:--- "+CallDate+" \nCall Time:--- "+CallTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+CallDuration+" \nTime in Milli:--- "+CallTimeMilli );
        //buffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
    if(timeShared==0)
    {
        db.addRowCall(CallName, CallNumber, CallType, CallDate, CallTime, CallDuration, CallTimeMilli); 
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Added to DB from start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sh.edit().putLong("Time", db.retrieveLastCallTime()).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        //timeRetrieved=db.retrieveLastCallTime();
        if(CallTimeMilli>timeShared)
        {
            db.addRowCall(CallName, CallNumber, CallType, CallDate, CallTime, CallDuration, CallTimeMilli); 
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "......Added to DB secnd time.........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sh.edit().putLong("Time", db.retrieveLastCallTime()).commit();

        }
    }
    }

    managedCursor.close();
    //long t=db.retrieveLastCallTime();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongValue "+t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

The service is called from settings.java, using a toggle button

```
call_track.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(call_track.isChecked())
                {
                    AlarmManager al=(AlarmManager)context_settins.getSystemService(context_settins.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent istart = new Intent(context_settins, callService.class);
                    PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 123456, istart, 0);
                    al.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),5000, p);
                    startService(new Intent(context_settins, callService.class));

                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context_settins, callService.class);
                    PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getService(context_settins, 123456, intent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alManager=(AlarmManager) context_settins.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alManager.cancel(sender);
                    stopService(new Intent(context_settins,callService.class));
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is , when i start the service it works fine, and data enters to DB, Bt, whenever the call comes, since the time interval is 5000.

But, after some time, the application force closes and shows following error details in log cat.

```
10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to startservice MainPRJ.Diary.callService@43e66740 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=MainPRJ.Diary/.callService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at MainPRJ.Diary.callService.getCallDetails(callService.java:64)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at MainPRJ.Diary.callService.onStart(callService.java:47)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)

10-19 21:36:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  ... 10 more
```

I have searched a lot, but didn't get any solution...
I'm new to android and can't understand whtas happening here...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Where is this `callService.java:64` ?

Comment: You have a NPE at callService.java, line 64

Comment: yaa.. the line number 64 is the 2nd line of code in getCallDetails()...                                       int number=managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);

Comment: and line number 47 is getCallDetails FunctionCall in onStart()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably `context` is null because you are trying to initialize it before service creation:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    context=callService.this;
    .....
}
```

Comment: To proper initialization on Context, do Context context=getApplicationContext()